# What is the alternative to std::atexit in C++

Tags: console

I wanted to remove file when the program is closed, but not ended. I tried to do it with function std::atexit, but its parameter can't be pointer to a function if that's class member function. So I was wondering is there any simple alternative?

```
class User 
{
    std::experimental::filesystem::path file_path;
    std::experimental::filesystem::path & get_file_path();
    void clean_file_path();
    void (User::*x)();
}
int main()
{
    std::experimental::filesystem::path p = user.get_file_path();
    user.x = & User::clean_file_path;
    std::ofstream output(p, std::ios::binary | std::ios::trunc);
    std::atexit(user.x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a static function inside your class and you could call "atexit" with a pointer to this static function:

```
class User
{
public:
    void clean();
    static void cleanStatic();
};

int main()
{
    void (User:: * pClean)() = &User::clean;
    void (*pCleanStatic)() = &User::cleanStatic;

    std::atexit(pCleanStatic);
}
```

You can register multiple functions with "atexit" but there is a limit to that number so maybe registering only one function that will handle the work for all the objects is a better solution.

One more thing: the type of pCleanStatic and the type of pClean are not the same:

- pCleanStatic is void(*)()
- pClean is void(User::*)()

"atexit" expects a parameter of type void(*)(). So only pCleanStatic will be accepted as a parameter. In Visual Studio, if you try to compile the code

```
std::atexit(pClean);
```

you'll get the following error:

```
error C2664: 'int atexit(void (__cdecl *)(void))': cannot convert argument 1 from 'void (__thiscall User::* )(void)' to 'void (__cdecl *)(void)'
```

mentioning the two different types.